# How do I set the path alias for nodes imported via RSS feed?

Tags: 8, nodes, feeds, path-aliases

In Drupal 8, I have created nodes of article type using the *Feeds* module, using a RSS feed as source.

How can I create path aliases for each of the imported nodes?

I have tried to map *`source:'item URL(link)`'* to *`target:'URL alias (path)'`*, but it doesn't work as it includes the whole link (including http://) as path alias.

Comment: Have you tried the Pathauto module already? To have aliases created upon node creation following your own customizable pattern?

Comment: I have just used Pathauto module and it worked. Thank you!